# react native detect webview scroll to bottom

Tags: typescript, react-native, webview

I am loading html to webview.

Trying to detect all the content is loaded and it is scrolled till bottom.
trying to implement T&C screen in mobile app.

Below is the code i tried

```
<WebView
          style={{flex: 1}}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          source={{uri: 'https://google.com'}} 
          javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}
          startInLoadingState={false}
          onLoadEnd={() => this.setState({isButtonEnabled: true})}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          scrollEnabled={false}
        />
```

also try to do this:  but onscroll is not giving proper on bottom offset

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
          <WebView
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            source={{uri: 'https://www.google.com'}} 
          />
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey the onScroll event is avaible in the WebView and you need to take into account the layoutMeasurement to calculate the actual bottom offset, try to update your webview as follow:

```js
<WebView
    style={{flex: 1}}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{uri: 'https://google.com'}} 
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    startInLoadingState={false}
    onLoadEnd={() => this.setState({isButtonEnabled: true})}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
    scrollEnabled={false}
    onScroll={(syntheticEvent) => {
        const { 
            contentOffset, 
            layoutMeasurement, 
            contentSize 
        } = syntheticEvent.nativeEvent;

        const offset = Math.round(contentOffset.y + layoutMeasurement.height);
        const contentHeight = Math.round(contentSize.height);

        if (offset == contentHeight) {
            console.log("end reached")
        }
    }}
/>
```

Hope this helps!